# How to make sure form cannot be submitted if text field is empty when user selects False Hit radio button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing something to prevent user from submitting HTML Form without leaving their remarks for False Hits.

**Conditions:**

- Only if False Hit radio button is selected
- The remarks text field cannot be empty (Compulsory)

Currently, I have used JavaScript to check if the text field (Remarks) is empty.

```
function empty() {
var x;
x = document.getElementById("roll-input").value;
if (x == "") {
    alert("Please enter remarks for false hits selected.");
    return false;
};
```

I am also able to check which radio button is selected with JavaScript.

```
<input type="radio" name="select" id="truehit" value="true" />
<input type="radio" name="select" id="falsehit" value="false" />

if(document.getElementById('falsehit').checked) {
  //False Hit radio button is checked
}
else if(document.getElementById('truehit').checked) {
  //True Hit radio button is checked
}
```

However, I am quite stuck at linking both conditions together. Is there a simpler method to this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

This is how my Form looks like.

```
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <br />

 <div align="center" class="h1">
 <h1>Entity Search</h1><br />   
 </div>

 </html>
 <br />

 <?php  
    include("db_connect.php"); //connect to database
    @$loginid = strtoupper(base64_decode($_POST['LanID'])); //to capture 
the user's LanID as the UserID
    if($loginid == "")
    {
        $userID = $_SESSION['loginid'];
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['loginid'] = $loginid;
        $userID = $_SESSION['loginid'];
}
$userID = $_SESSION['loginid'];

//to insert date and time of the records
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
$Date = date('Y-m-d');
$Time = date ('h:i:s a');

$userID = $_SESSION['loginid'];
$loginid = "";

$entityfromform = $_GET["entity"];
?>

<br />

<?php
//connection to database
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test","UID"=>$test,"PWD"=>$test);
$db_connect=sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

//to retrieve the department name from the user database and insert 
department name of the user into the records
    $namesql = "SELECT Name, DeptName, Role FROM RPDB.dbo.Userdb WHERE 
   LanID='$userID';";
$name_query = sqlsrv_query($db_connect,$namesql);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($name_query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $nameontop = iconv("gb2312","UTF-8",$row['Name']);
    $admincheck = iconv("gb2312","UTF-8",$row["Role"]);
    $deptnamecheck = iconv("gb2312","UTF-8",$row["DeptName"]);
}

$negative = "Negative Hit: No results found.<br />";
$result = "$entityfromform <br />Negative Hit: No results found.<br />"; 
//variable to insert into the table as result

//search for keyword from form in the Entity Table List where Name = 
keyword
$entitysql = "SELECT * FROM RPDB.dbo.entitysearch_table WHERE Name LIKE 
'%" . $entityfromform . "%' OR Name = '".$entityfromform."'";
$entity_query = sqlsrv_query($db_connect,$entitysql);

//variables
$i=0;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($entity_query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{           
    $name[$i] = $row["Name"];
    $brn[$i] = $row["Business_Registration_Number"];
    $address[$i] = $row["Registered_Address"];
$group[$i] = $row["Applicable_Limb_of_Related_Party_Group"];
$selectradio[$i] = 'selectradio'.$i;
$text[$i] = 'text'.$i;
$i++;
}   
      if(@$name != NULL) //Positive Result
    {
        echo "<input type='button' name=uncheck' value='Uncheck All' 
class='uncheck' onClick='window.location.reload()'>"; //uncheck all 
function where it clears all changes
        echo "<h2><div align='center'>Results found for: 
$entityfromform</div></h2><br />";
         //table to display the data
             echo "<div align='center'>
            <table> 
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Business Registration Number</th>
            <th>Registered Address</th>
            <th>Applicable Limb of Related Party Group</th>
            <th>True Hit</th>
            <th>False Hit</th>
            <th>Unable To Ascertain</th>
            <th>Remarks, for false hit</th>
        </tr>
    </div>";
    echo "<strong><div class='wording'>Positive Hit: </div></strong>";
    echo "<br /><br />";
    $x=0;
    ?>
    <!--The form data is sent for processing to action_handler.php by HTTP POST method-->
    <form method="post" id="form" action="action_handler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
    //data displayed in tables along with checkboxes for true hit, false hit, unable to ascertain and text box for remarks where applicable
    for($x=0;$x<$i;$x++)
    {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $name[$x] . "</td>
        <td>". $brn[$x] . "</td>
        <td>". $address[$x] . "</td>
        <td>". $group[$x] . "</td>
        
        <td>
        <label class='container'>
        <input type='radio'   id='truehit' name='".$selectradio[$x]."' value='true hit' class='btn' required>
        <span class='checkmark'></span>
        </label>
        </td>
        
        <td>
        <label class='container'>
        <input type='radio'  id='falsehit' name='".$selectradio[$x]."' value='false hit' class='btn'>
        <span class='checkmark'></span>
        </label>
        </td>
        
        <td>
        <label class='container'>
        <input type='radio'  id='unabletoascertain' name='".$selectradio[$x]."' value='unabletoascertain' class='btn'>
        <span class='checkmark'></span>
        </label>
        </td>
        
        <td>
        <label><input type='text' name='".$text[$x]."'> 
        </label>
        </td>
        
        </tr>" ;
    }
    echo "</table>"; //table closed
    echo "<br /><br /><br />";
    echo "<input type='button' value='Submit' class='submit' onClick='empty()'>"; //submit button to confirm
    ?>
    </form>
    <?php
    //sessions to be used in others
    $_SESSION['num'] = $x;
    $_SESSION['entityfromform'] = $entityfromform;
}
else 
{
    echo "<div align='center'><h2>Results found for: $entityfromform</h2> 
   <br />";
        echo "<div class='wording' align='center'>$negative</div><br><br> 
   <br>";
            
        }
    ?>

</table>
</body>
```

[image: This is how it looks like. I have blurred out the private and confidential data]

[image: Inspect element]

Comment: I would appriciate if you can accept as answer to my answer if that has solved what you were looking at. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your empty() function does not return anything if the textbox has a value and hence for that condition it is undefined; you can create a function for your requirement like:

```
function doSubmit() 
{
   if(document.getElementById('falsehit').checked)
   {
      if(document.getElementById("roll-input").value == '')
      {
         alert("Please enter remarks for false hits selected.");
         return false;
      }
   }
return true;
}
```

and call this method to validate, so if `falsehit` is `checked` and `remarks` has a value it'll return `true` or else `false`.

Hope this helps; let me know if I'm missing to understand your problem here..

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of `if` statements like below. This basically checks if the `falsehit` radio button is checked. If it is, then it checks if the text is empty. If the text is empty, it alerts what you wanted it to. If the text isn't empty, it submit's the form.

Also, if `falsehit` is not checked, it automatically submit's the form.

**As per request in the comments:** Now I get every radio button, and loop through them to check if they're selected. If they aren't, you get an alert message saying `Please select all accordingly`. Otherwise, it just works the same as before.

```js
function empty() {
  var text;
  var groups = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=group]");
  var selected = {};
  var radioButtons;
  var submitForm = true;

  groups.forEach(e1 => {
    radioButtons = e1.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
    radioButtons.forEach(e2 => {
      if (e2.checked) {
        selected[e1.id] = true;
      }
    });

    if (selected[e1.id] == undefined) {
      selected[e1.id] = false;
    }
  });

  groups.forEach(e => {
    text = e.children[0].value;
    for (var i = 0; i < e.children.length; i++) {
      if (e.children[i].id == "falsehit") {
        if (e.children[i].checked) {
          if (text.length == 0) {
            alert("Please enter remarks for false hits selected.");
            submitForm = false;
          }
        } else if (selected[e.id]) {
          //Don't need to do anything. Just need to prevent the next else from accessing these values
        } else {
          alert("Please select all accordingly.");
          submitForm = false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  
  if (submitForm) {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <fieldset id="group1">
    <input type="text" id="roll-input" />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="truehit" value="true" />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="falsehit" value="false" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="group2">
    <input type="text" id="roll-input" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" id="truehit" value="true" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" id="falsehit" value="false" />
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="empty()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Aniket G! Thanks for your help. I would like to ask what should be done if I want to ensure that user selects one radio button on every row in other words how to check for empty radio buttons and prompt alert "Please select all accordingly."  before they are able to submit the form. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AngelLim fixed it. Is that how you wanted it?

Comment: I have multiple rows of radio buttons displaying based on the results. However, the updated codes currently only allows the following scenarios :

1) Able to submit form if first row meets the criteria of False Hit radio button selected, text field not empty. But, the other rows radio buttons are left empty.

2) Able to submit form as long as the first row radio button is selected.

Comment: Based on the scenarios, I think the code is only working for the first row.

Comment: @AngelLim Does each row of radio buttons have an `<input type="text">` as well?

Comment: yes, each row have. I have posted the code for my form on my question.

Comment: @AngelLim can you click multiple of the radio buttons? Or does it only let you select one?

Comment: Each row, I am only allowed to select one. And, I am able to select on on every row.

Comment: @AngelLim ok I updated my snippet. I think it should work now. Please tell me if you need me to change anything. **So sorry, but I won't be able to explain it. It'll be way too much to explain. I'll try to add comments as much as possible to help you understand. Use `console.log()` in various places if you want to understand it better.**

Comment: Is it possible for you to update your snippet based on my form code above? Right now, I think its quite different from my code and I would need to change a lot.

Comment: @AngelLim let me take a look

Comment: @AngelLim I would need the php variables

Comment: I have added all my codes including the PHP side on my question, hope it helps. Thank you.

Comment: @AngelLim sorry, but that won't help me. You're trying to access a local database, which I don't have access to. Could you find out how the html renders (Right Click and then click Inspect Element)? I need your code, but all in html (without any PHP). **So sorry for being this picky, but its necessary**

Comment: Sorry the codes are actually on the work's intranet, and I am not able to export it out. I don't quite understand... actually my form is done in the PHP.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the Inspect Element in the question. @Aniket G

Comment: @AngelLim ok thanks. That helps. I'll work on the solution and comment to you when I'm done